Is it possible to derive Schrödinger's equation from Hamilton's equations?
Accepting the postulates of quantum mechanics, so promoting the classical dynamical variables to operators with appropriate commutation relations, is it possible to "derive" Schrödinger's equation
$$ih\frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\psi(t)\rangle = H |\psi (t)\rangle.\tag{1}$$
Directly from Hamilton's equations of motion? So I am asking for a derivation that avoids the use of Poisson's brackets and avoids the use of the Heisenberg picture. Is it feasible? Or are we forced to introduce the concept of Poisson's brackets to show the parallelism between the classical EOM and the QM EOM in the Heisenberg picture?

Well, the operator form of Hamilton's equations is the Heisenberg EOM in the Heisenberg picture, which in turn is equivalent to the TDSE in the Schrödinger picture.

@Qmechanic what you are mentioning doesn't involve the use of Poisson's brakets right? If so would you mind expanding on it in an answer?

Schroedinger himself was closer to Hamilton-Jacobi than PBs (Dirac's brilliant cutting through the Gordian knots of the time), and approached the issue in four (!) maddening gyrations, which he then summarized more clearly in English !! So you want to strip Dirac off Schroedinger...


First of all, it should be stressed that the TDSE (1) cannot be derived from classical physics alone, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

However, assuming that the classical system at hand can be quantized, the operator form of Hamilton's equations
$$ d_tA(t)~=~\{A(t), H(t)\}_{PB} + \partial_tA(t) \tag{CM}$$
is the Heisenberg EOM
$$d_t\hat{A}_H(t)~=~\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{A}_H(t),\hat{H}_H(t)] +(\partial_t\hat{A}_S)_H.\tag{QM}$$
in the Heisenberg picture, which in turn is equivalent to the TDSE (1) in the Schrödinger picture.


